# Can the embedding dimension of a finite local algebra change after restricting to a finite subfield?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

The embedding dimension of a commutative $k$-algebra is the minimum $n$ such that it is a quotient of the polynomial algebra in $n$-variables.

The embedding dimension of $\mathbb{F}_2\times \mathbb{F}_2$ is $1$ because it is a quotient of $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ by the product of the ideals $(x)$ and $(x+1)$.

The embedding dimension of $\mathbb{F}_2\times \mathbb{F}_2\times \mathbb{F}_2$ is $2$ because it is not a quotient of $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ but it is a quotient of $\mathbb{F}_2[x, y]$ by the product of the ideals $(x, y)$, $(x+1, y)$ and $(x, y+1)$.

Let $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}/\mathbb{F}_q$ be an extension of finite fields. Can the embedding dimension of a finite local $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$-algebra be different if we consider it as an $\mathbb{F}_q$-algebra?

For example $\mathbb{F}_4[x]/(x^2)$ has embedding dimension $1$ as a $\mathbb{F}_4$-algebra and it has embedding dimension $1$ as a $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra since $\mathbb{F}_4[x]/(x^2)\cong \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^4+x^2+1)$.

P.S. As YCor points out this happens for $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ itself so let us consider only the case of positive dimension.

Comment: There is a quite obvious case: when the algebra is $\mathbf{F}_{q^n}$ itself with $n\ge 2$: its "embedding dimension" is then 0 as $\mathbf{F}_{q^n}$-algebra but 1 as $\mathbf{F}_{q}$-algebra.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I had missed that word!